# Bizarre memory issue, for loops initializing incorrectly and modifying heap memory

Tags: c

I'm having a memory related issue. Very strange behavior where initializing a for loop with stack variables is somehow changing values in heap memory. Never seen anything like this.

I have this main loop where I set some things up in heap and call some functions.

```
int main()
{
    double **A = malloc(4 * sizeof(double *));
    A[0] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
    A[1] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
    A[2] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
    A[3] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
    
    double **I = malloc(4 * sizeof(double *));
    I[0] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
    I[1] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
    I[2] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
    I[3] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
    
    int *P = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    
    A[0][0] = -1; A[0][1] = 8; A[0][2] = 9; A[0][3] = -6;
    A[1][0] = 3; A[1][1] = 4; A[1][2] = 0; A[1][3] = 1;
    A[2][0] = 0; A[2][1] = 2; A[2][2] = 0; A[2][3] = 0;
    A[3][0] = 0; A[3][1] = 0; A[3][2] = -3; A[3][3] = 1;
    
    LUPDecompose(A, 4, P);
    LUPInvert(A, P, 4, I);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The functions I call are the following two. They're pretty complicated but seem totally fine.

```
void LUPDecompose(double **A, int N, int *P)
{
    int i, j, k, imax; 
    double maxA, *ptr, absA;

    for (i = 0; i <= N; i++)
        P[i] = i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        maxA = 0.0;
        imax = i;

        for (k = i; k < N; k++)
            if ((absA = fabs(A[k][i])) > maxA) { 
                maxA = absA;
                imax = k;
            }

        if (imax != i) {
            j = P[i];
            P[i] = P[imax];
            P[imax] = j;

            ptr = A[i];
            A[i] = A[imax];
            A[imax] = ptr;

            P[N]++;
        }

        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            A[j][i] /= A[i][i];

            for (k = i + 1; k < N; k++)
                A[j][k] -= A[j][i] * A[i][k];
        }
    }
}
```

```
void LUPInvert(double **A, int *P, int N, double **IA)
{  
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (P[i] == j) 
                IA[i][j] = 1.0;
            else
                IA[i][j] = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                IA[i][j] -= A[i][k] * IA[k][j];
            }
        }
        
        printf("observe... %f (j %d)\n", IA[3][0], j);

        for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < N; k++) {
                printf("N %d k %d ...magic %f (j %d)\n", N, k, IA[3][0], j);
                IA[i][j] -= A[i][k] * IA[k][j];
            }
            IA[i][j] = IA[i][j] / A[i][i];
        }
    }
}
```

When running this code, the for loop in the function `LUPInvert` initializes with `k` as `N - 1` instead of `N`. Also the heap value `AI[3][0]` gets modified there. It gets modified to `0xbec00000` which sure seems like some memory overflow issue as it's full of zeroes, but I don't see it.
Can run this code and see the behavior here https://onlinegdb.com/SkZUlpmDD.

Sample of stdout:

```
observe... -0.214286 (j 0)                                                                                                                                                                     
N 4 k 3 ...magic -0.375000 (j 0)                                                                                                                                                               
N 4 k 2 ...magic -0.375000 (j 0)                                                                                                                                                               
N 4 k 3 ...magic -0.375000 (j 0)                                                                                                                                                               
N 4 k 1 ...magic -0.375000 (j 0)                                                                                                                                                               
N 4 k 2 ...magic -0.375000 (j 0)                                                                                                                                                               
N 4 k 3 ...magic -0.375000 (j 0)                                                                                                                                                               
observe... -0.375000 (j 1)                                                                                                                                                                     
N 4 k 3 ...magic -0.375000 (j 1)                                                                                                                                                               
N 4 k 2 ...magic -0.375000 (j 1)
```

It's as if it's forcing the loop to start (even tho it shouldn't as pointed out in comments), but in order to do so it has to set its values weirdly that causes this corruption.

Comment: `k as N - 1 instead of N` The inner loop runs for `k < N` so it has zero iterations when `k = N`.

Comment: When I run your code on onlinegdb, `IA[3][0]` displays as -3.75.

Comment: For j=0, first iteration, it first prints -0.214286 for me, then -0.375000 as soon as it enters the for loop and never changes after that. I can't explain that.

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't even enter the for loop. But it does! Somehow. I would also expect 0 iterations. I found this code from wikipedia btw, it's broken for sure, but something else is seriously wrong here.

Comment: @OlafWillocx The first iteration with `i = 3` skips over the `k` loop, then assigns `A[3][0]`. The next iteration with `i = 2` enters the inner loop with `k = 3` and finds the previously modified `A[3][0]`. Where do you see the problem?

Comment: Ah I tihnk I see it; inner for loops only starts at i = N - 2 and by then IA[3][0] in particular has been divided by A[0][0] and modified. Thanks!